# Set active state to a url with similar begin (PHP)

Tags: php, menu

I'm using the following code to set the active state in my menu:

```
<li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php' ? 'active' : '';?>">
<a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'projects.php' ? 'active' : '';?>">
<a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
```

And It works fine for the specific url such as projects.php, but also we had the following "projects" and we want to set the active state in the menu for them:

- project-client-name.php
- project-client-name-2.php
- project-client-name-3.php

Is there any alternative to set the active state to a url who it **begins** or contains "**project**" in the url, in this way it works for **project**-client-name.php and **project**s.php:

```
<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'project' ? 'active' : '';?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
<?php echo preg_match("/^(project){1}(.){0,}\w+/", basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) ? 'active' : ''; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that it's a weird solution, you could use [strpos()](https://php.net/strpos) or [preg_match()](https://php.net/preg_match)

```
<?php echo strpos(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 'project') !== FALSE ? 'active' : '';?>
```

strpos looks for first occurence of substring and returns it's int position or `FALSE` if it's not found